# creating and checking URL in Java

Tags: java, api, url

I have a use case where values my function accepts could be of type:-

```
1. mailto:abc@abc.com
2. tel:3402904323
3. http(s)://www.google.com
4. www.google.com
5. //www.google.com
6. /content/abc/def/index
7. javascript:;
8. blank
9. #
10. http(s)://www.google.com/index.html#abc
11. http(s)://www.google.com/index.html
```

All these are to be treated as valid and i have to create a URL out of them for e.g. for input 6 i would need to append (.html). For 7th i might need to escapeHtml and rest could be returned as is.
Is there a standard java API to do this or any standard logic i could put into doing this.
Please help.

Comment: Only those 11 values can be valid matches?  You'll need to create a few RegEx patterns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [String#matches](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-) with the the following regular expressions, respectively.

1. `(?i)mailto:[a-z0-9]{1,}[.a-z0-9]*@[a-z0-9]{1,}[.a-z0-9].[a-z0-9]{2,}`
2. `tel:[0-9]{10}`
3. `http[s]{0,}://`
4. `www\.[a-z0-9\-]{1,}\.com`
5. `//www\.[a-z0-9\-]{1,}\.com`
6. `/content/([a-z0-9\.\-]{1,}/*)*`
7. `nice try`
8. `[^\w\W]*`
9. `#`
10. `http[s]*://[a-z0-9-]{1,}\.[a-z0-9-]{1,}\.com/([a-z0-9-_%\?\=]{1,}/)*[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,}\.html#[a-zA-Z_\-\.]{1,}`
11. `http[s]*://[a-z0-9-]{1,}\.[a-z0-9-]{1,}\.com/([a-z0-9-_%\?\=]{1,}/)*[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,}\.html[a-zA-Z_\-\.]{1,}`

Here is an example of using a regular expression, in this case it will return a boolean value (it matches or it doesn't match)

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    String pattern = "http[s]*://[a-z0-9-]{1,}\\.[a-z0-9-]{1,}\\.com/([a-z0-9-_%\\?\\=]{1,}/)*[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,}\\.html#[a-zA-Z_\\-\\.]{1,}";

    String string = "http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-";

    /*
     * This will print the boolean literal true or false
     */
    System.out.println( string.matches(pattern) );

}
```

Comment: Note the `(?i)` flag in the first pattern.  In Java this will render the pattern case-insensitive.  `a-z` means all lower case letters where `A-Z` is for uppercase.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to create a `java.net.URI` with the string. If there is a syntax error you will get a `URISyntaxException`. All the above pass provided that "http(s)" really means "http" and "https" separately. If you need to restrict the scheme to what is shown above, just get the scheme and look it up in a table, and fail it if isn't there.